# Giving Position to values in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

i'm working on assigning positions to values in an arraylist in java.

For example An `ArrayList containing {5,6,3,1,9,10,0,2,6}`.

How can I correctly assign positions to the numbers to have something like this `{5th,3rd,7th 2nd,1st,8th, 6th,3rd}`.

I have successfully sorted the arraylist containing the numbers in java.

Am now stuck at giving position to the numbers.

Comment: when you say giving position do you mean adding the "st","nd","rd" and "th" ?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking how you would "remember" for the sorted array, where its entries where before sorting? Or the other way round: for an unsorted array, to know where an entry would go after sorting?

Comment: I mean how do I give positions(rank) to the elements in the arrayList. Not the suffixes now.

Comment: @ALABIJesujoba we are well aware that rank is a synonym of position but it is still unclear what the ranking is based on how it should be implemented. Could you also add the code you are using so we can understand what you want to do?

Comment: Ok, in a class of 9 students, after their CA test they had the following scores {5,6,3,1,9,10,0,2,6}. The task is now assigning position to the students. to have the candidate that had 10 which is the highes score (to be the first position), 9(second), 6(third), etc.......Just trying to automate the way our school teachers assign positions to students in a class. Is this clearer?

Comment: @ALABIJesujoba much cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Would something like this work?

```
    public static ArrayList<String> getPositions(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    ArrayList<String> positions = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] endings = { "th", "st", "nd", "rd" };
    Integer last = 100;
    Integer lastRank = 1;
    for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
        int position = index + 1;
        if (last == list.get(index)) {
            position = lastRank;
        }
        int remainder = position % 10;
        String rank = position + "";
        String ending = endings[0];
        if (remainder <= 3) {
            if ((position % 100) - remainder != 10) {
                ending = endings[remainder];
            }
        }
        rank = rank + ending;
        last = list.get(index);
        lastRank = position;
        positions.add(rank);
    }
    return positions;
}
```

I would also like to give credit to [Robert van der Spek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6324924/robert-van-der-spek[1]) for coming up with a more efficient way to assign the ending of the position.

Comment: Ok, in a class of 9 students, after their CA test they had the following scores {5,6,3,1,9,10,0,2,6}. The task is now assigning position to the students. to have the candidate that had 10 which is the highes score (to be the first position), 9(second), 6(third), etc.......Just trying to automate the way our school teachers assign positions to students in a class. Is this clearer?

Comment: @ALABIJesujoba the method accepts a sorted **arrayList** of scores and returns an **arrayList** of ranks. Isn't this what you asked for? For example if you do `getPositions([10,8,6,4,3]);` the output will be ["1st","2nd","3rd","4th","5th"]

Comment: @ALABIJesujoba Could you then accept the answer? the small tick under the up/down-vote buttons

Comment: @ALABIJesujoba what is the problem then?

Comment: @ALABIJesujoba are you sure you have the latest version, because it has been edited.

Comment: When I executed the program using getPositions([10,8,6,4,3])  I got                 10th
8st
6nd
4rd
3th instead of 1st 2nd 3rd 4th.....

Comment: @ALABIJesujoba The answer had been edited when did you check it? Try again with the new one.

Comment: Ok, it had a bug but I've resolved that. But wont work for the cases where their are multiple scores eg getPositions([10,6,6,4,3])

Comment: Yes, 1st, 2nd, 2nd, 4th, 5th. Note the position of the suffixes. cos what I have after executing the program is  1th
2st
3nd
4th
5th

Comment: @ALABIJesujoba Done!

Comment: Weldone boss. Perfect but instead of 11th it is giving 11st.

Comment: @ALABIJesujoba Fixed it

Comment: Not at all. @nick zoum

Comment: @ALABIJesujoba sorry had problem uploading check again.

Answer (score 1):

An edit after you clarified your question:

```
double[] grades = {10.0, 8.8, 8.7, 7.0, 6.0, 4.3}; // Mock data

for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    String position = numberToPositionString(i + 1);
    System.out.println(position + " with the grade " + grades[i]);
}
```

with the function:

```
public String numberToPositionString(int number) {
    String[] concatPosition = { "th", "st", "nd", "rd"};
    if(number > 3 && number < -3) {
        return number + "th";
    }
    else {
        return number + concatPosition[Math.abs(number)];
    }
}
```

will generate a result like this:

- 1st with the grade 10
- 2nd with the grade 8.8
- 3rd with the grade 8.7
- 4th with the grade 7.0
- 5th with the grade 6.0
- 6th with the grade 4.3

Off course you should modify it to fit your needs. You might even consider using a TreeMap instead of an array. It would enable you to match student name and grade. Hope this was helpful to you.

Comment: Ok, in a class of 9 students, after their CA test they had the following scores {5,6,3,1,9,10,0,2,6}. The task is now assigning position to the students. to have the candidate that had 10 which is the highes score (to be the first position), 9(second), 6(third), etc.......Just trying to automate the way our school teachers assign positions to students in a class. Is this clearer?

Comment: I have changed my answer after you clarified your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add the ending at the end then do:

```
ArrayList<String> positions = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> endings =  new ArrayList<String>();
endings.add("st");
endings.add("nd");
endings.add("rd");
endings.add("th");
for(Integer value: arrayList){
    String ending = endings.get(3);
    if(value < 4){
        ending = endings.get(value-1);
    }
    positions.add(value + ending);
}
```

Comment: Not the ending now but the real process of ranking the array.